# Regex test starting by an accent

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex pattern to find multiple occurrences of a given word (supplied by the Database) in a text.
The pattern also ignores the word if it is within a link.

The pattern has been working fine until now, but I have encountered a problem. If the word starts with an accent (and I specify starts because if it has the accent in the word that isn't a problem its only if it starts with an accent) the word will not match.

To view the problem [go to RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) and paste this in the first box:

```
\bétest(?![^<]*</a>)\b
```

and this in the second box

```
herp derp derp test herp derp derp derp étest herp derp derp derp <a>test</a>
```

You can remove the "é" to see what it is its supposed to be returning

Answer (score 0):

`\b` indicates a boundary between a word and a non-word character. Put another way, it asserts something akin to `(?<=\w)(?=\W)|(?<=\W)(?=\w)` (of course, lookbehinds aren't a thing in JavaScript, but this is just a demonstration).

`é` is not a word character. Therefore, there is no word boundary between it and the space.

However, there *is* a word boundary between it and the `t`:

```
"étest".match(/é\btest/)
> ["étest"]
```